# user should enter int, repeat if anything else is entered

Tags: c#, .net

First of all, I am a complete newbie at programming and c#..so here is my dilemma.

The user should only enter a number, entering anything else should fail and repeat the question.

I have been using try catch but, as soon as the error gets thrown the user doesn't have a second chance to enter a number again, I just get an error and the ConsoleApp Closes.

This is my code atm

```
static public int AskInt(string question)
{
    try
    {
        Console.Write(question);
        return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new FormatException("Please Enter a Number");
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use tryparse instead of direct casting

Comment: You need a loop. The try/catch construct does not have any kind of "retry" functionality, as it appears you're expecting. When the input is valid, exit the loop.

Comment: And how does one do that ? i was thinking something like while readline is not int ? Or something along those lines..

Comment: this is possible duplicate of lots of questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static public int AskInt(string question)
{
    int answer = 0;
    bool successfullyParsed = false;
    do
    {
        Console.Write(question);
        successfullyParsed = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var parsedAnswer);
        if(!successfullyParsed){
            Console.WriteLine("Only Numbers, dude");
        }
        answer = parsedAnswer;

    } while (!successfullyParsed);


    return answer;
}
```

Explaining a bit. TryParse will return a boolean indicating the success of the operation and an out variable with the result.

I can't return the parsedAnswer because it is in the context of the do loop. 
You can make this code less legible but short. I tried to make it this why to be kinda of self explanatory.

Comment: Why didn't you explain a bit? Why do you need parsedAnswer when answer is just as good to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Sorry about it. Just commented the post with some explanation.

Comment: Where could i add a message in your code that lets the user know, "Only numbers allowed ? " Btw it works great how it is now.

Comment: Just edited with the change. Sorry for the previous comment, it barely change.

Comment: You broke it, The "Only Numbers, dude" error message will print no matter what.

Comment: @BrunoAvelar, "Only Numbers dude" should be printed, when successfullyParsed is false.

Comment: Exactley, it prints with the number entered.

Comment: Sorry. It was late night :(

Answer (score 1):

Use below code which uses `TryParse` of `int` to parse the entered string. If TryParse succeed then it will break the `while` loop.

```
public static int AskInt(string question)
{
        int questionId;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(question);
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(input , out questionId))
            {
                 break;
            }
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=1;
while(i==1)
{
  try {
            Console.WriteLine("your question");
            int number= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            i=0;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
          i=1;
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Number");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static public int AskInt(string question)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        Console.Write(question);

        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result))
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```